# Getting Exception trying to delete a Local User Group using Directory Services Account Management in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, directoryservices, account-management

I'm trying to programmatically delete a local user group. I'm using the following code which I've cobbled together from various examples online. From everything I've read, it should work. But the Delete line throws an exception.

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Machine );
GroupPrincipal group = new GroupPrincipal( context );
PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher( group );
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = ps.FindAll();
Principal foundGroup = results.SingleOrDefault( item => item.Name == groupName );
if(foundGroup != null)
    foundGroup.Delete(); // Here occurs the InvalidOperationException
```

This throws an `InvalidOperationException` with the message:

> The Active Directory object located at the path WinNT://LOREM/IPSUM is not a container."

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to this Active Directory stuff.

Comment: did you tried and get way to ***delete group*** ?

Answer (score 1):

This was asked a while ago, but I ran into this issue today. It seems that there is a bug in the Group and UserPrincipal library. This is how I worked around it for anyone who runs into this in the future:

For groups:

```
string groupName = "myGroup";

// Workaround: WinNT://DOMAIN/USER is not a container even if group is empty
using (var root = new DirectoryEntry($"WinNT://{Environment.MachineName}"))
using (var group = root.Children.Find(groupName, "group"))
{
    root.Children.Remove(group);
    result = true;
}
```

For user accounts:

```
string userAccountName = "myUser";

// Workaround: WinNT://DOMAIN/USER is not a container issue
using (var root = new DirectoryEntry($"WinNT://{Environment.MachineName}"))
using (var userAccount = root.Children.Find(userAccountName))
{
    root.Children.Remove(userAccount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `PrincipalSearchResult<GroupPrincipal>`?

I am also not sure if your .SingleOrDefault is used correctly. Can you try:

```
results.Where(item => item.Name == groupName).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: "PrincipalSearchResult<GroupPrincipal>" won't compile because FindAll returns "PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>".
And changing the LINQ query had no effect.